# Numerical analysis: what is the error term for the rule...?

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, fractions, error-propagation

The question goes: derive the error term for the rule $phi$ to approximate the third derivative of f(a). I have attached a screenshot [image: here]

I understand how to take the Taylor series in the hint, but the 4 expressions in the numerator of the rule are throwing me off. Would I separate the fraction into two fractions? And then add the error terms? That doesn't seem right to me...

Or would there be 4 different coefficients for each term in the expansion? Again, that doesn't seem right to me...

Comment: The whole numerator should have one overall Taylor expansion; presumably it looks like $2f'''(a)h^3+\dots$. Find the first term in the "..."

Answer (score 1):

Consider, around $h=0$, Taylor expansion $$f(a+\alpha h)=f(a)+\alpha  h f'(a)+\frac{1}{2} \alpha ^2 h^2 f''(a)+\frac{1}{6} \alpha ^3 h^3
   f^{(3)}(a)+\frac{1}{24} \alpha ^4 h^4 f^{(4)}(a)+\frac{1}{120} \alpha ^5 h^5
   f^{(5)}(a)+O\left(h^6\right)$$ Apply it to $\alpha=+2,+1,-1,-2$ to get $$f(a+2 h)-2 f(a+ h)+2 f(a- h)-f(a-2 h)=2 h^3 f^{(3)}(a)+\frac{1}{2} h^5 f^{(5)}(a)+O\left(h^6\right)$$

Using the hint, calculations can be faster since $$f(a+\alpha h)-f(a-\alpha h)=2 \alpha  h f'(a)+\frac{1}{3} \alpha ^3 h^3 f^{(3)}(a)+\frac{1}{60} \alpha ^5 h^5
   f^{(5)}(a)+O\left(h^6\right)$$

Comment: Because of symmetry, the last two $O(h^6)$ really are $O(h^7)$ (provided the function is smooth enough).

Comment: So will I plug in the values of a separately and then sum all the parts together?

Comment: Also, the question asks for the error term to approximate f'(3) so wouldn't the error term be of the order f'(4) ?